# Can machine accounts use a SQL Server login for an AD group they belong to?

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I have a need to log into a remote SQL Server instance from a service running as Local System, which means it will utilize the machine account (e.g., `MYDOMAIN\MYSERVER$`) as credentials when authenticating with SQL Server. This works fine if I add a login for this machine account specifically.

However, I just tried adding a login for an Active Directory *group* containing the machine account in question, and the service was unable to connect, resulting in the following Application log message:

```
Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\MYSERVER$'. 
    Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.
```

I have successfully utilized this group login approach in the past for actual *users*, where I can simply add a SQL Server login for a group (e.g., `MYDOMAIN\SomeDevelopers`) and any members of the group can then connect with their own Windows credentials.

Is there something different about machine accounts and/or AD groups that contain them that would prevent the same thing from working there? Is there any way around it aside from configuring the individual machine account logins explicitly as I've done in the past?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it turns out this was an AD-replication timing issue. The group in question had been newly established, and had not yet replicated to the data center where the SQL Server in question was located. After enough time passed, I was able to utilize the AD group successfully as a SQL Server login, and machines belonging to that group correctly inherited the permissions assigned to the group.